# Why these date setDate( day+1 ) not adding 24 hours?

Tags: javascript

[Please help me improve the title if it doesn't describe the question clear]

---

I found this weird thing when I develop a jquery plugin:

```
var a = new Date('1986-05-03');
a.setHours(0,0,0,0);
// a = Sat May 03 1986 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)

a.setDate( a.getDate() + 1 );
// a = Sat May 03 1986 23:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)
```

It actually adds 23 hours

There's some other ticket mentioned daylight savings, but May 3 is not the beginning of daylight saving days, right ?

Further, I tried to print all the not-24-hours date, here's my code:

```
var start = new Date('1900-01-01'); // FYI, IE8- doesn't support this kind of date construction
var end = new Date('2014-01-01');
start.setHours(0,0,0,0);
end.setHours(0,0,0,0);

while (start.getTime() < end.getTime()) {
    var oneMoreDay = new Date(start.getTime()); 
    oneMoreDay.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
    var diff = oneMoreDay.getTime() - start.getTime();
    if (diff != 86400000) {
        console.log(start);
    }
    start = oneMoreDay;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Sat May 03 1986 23:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST) VM124:12
Fri Sep 12 1986 23:00:00 GMT+0900 (CST) VM124:12
Sat Apr 11 1987 23:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST) VM124:12
Fri Sep 11 1987 23:00:00 GMT+0900 (CST) VM124:12
Sat Apr 09 1988 23:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST) VM124:12
Fri Sep 09 1988 23:00:00 GMT+0900 (CST) VM124:12
Sat Apr 15 1989 23:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST) VM124:12
Fri Sep 15 1989 23:00:00 GMT+0900 (CST) VM124:12
Sat Apr 14 1990 23:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST) VM124:12
Fri Sep 14 1990 23:00:00 GMT+0900 (CST) VM124:12
Sat Apr 13 1991 23:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST) VM124:12
Fri Sep 13 1991 23:00:00 GMT+0900 (CST)
```

So, it's not in every year! Why are these date special?

Comment: That _is_ really odd...

Comment: No repo(http://jsfiddle.net/Fr5VL/) from my side.

Comment: In chrome, the full output shows a diff of 23 or 25 hours on the twice a year daylight savings transitions and that's all it shows (which is expected).

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan I reproduce it in your jsfiddle, it seems related to your local timezone. you can print those not-24-hour dates to see what are they in your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is every April/May and September and it gives you a different GMT offset. That is daylight savings.

[From Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_China#People.27s_Republic_of_China)

> After the Chinese Civil War, in 1949, a unified time zone—GMT+8—was
>   established by the People's Republic of China for all its territories,
>   called Beijing Time (sometimes known as Chinese Standard Time).
>   Daylight saving time was observed from 1986 to 1991.

It isn't a problem. The time is correct. The time offset just changes. Ignore it, all calculation will work correctly.

P.S. That is the first time I had to research the Chinese Civil War for stack overflow.

Comment: Is that mean I have this problem because my local time is Chinese time?

Comment: It isn't a problem. The time is correct. The time offset just changes. Ignore it, all calculation will work correctly.

Comment: +1 for Chinese civil war research :) Not the first [odd Asian time-zone questions I've seen around here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/1348195).

Comment: Thank you so much ! I'm working on a timeline widget so I need the time increase by exactly 24 hours. I'm using `a.setTime(a.getTime()+86400000);` now and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

It is two days (beginning and end) for every year that using a daylight-saving calendar in your local timezone.

Daylight saving time was observed only from 1986 to 1991 in China, so I ran the code in Chinese time zone I got the above results.

But if I change my timezone to London time, I get the different output, it's two days in almost every year, March and October.

You can run that code in different timezone to see the differences.